# How Angular Controller flow works?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have the following module:

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('ModBrowser',['ModUserCredentials','ModContentGroup']);

app.directive('browser', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "angular_js/Browser/Browser.html",
        controller: BrowserController,
        controllerAs: 'ctrlBrowser'
    }
});

function BrowserController($http, $rootScope, UserCredentials){
    var self = this;

    self.active = false;

    self.folders = [];
    self.files = [];
    self.models = [];

    self.Init = function(){
        self.active = true;

        var url = "curl.php";
        var data = {
            path: "ViewFiles",
            parent_id: "{\"user_id\":\"" + UserCredentials.ID + "\",\"parent_id\":\"" + $rootScope.selectedFolder + "\"}"
        };

        $http.post(url, data).then(function(response){
            for(var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                if(response.data[i].object_type.trim() == "FOLDER"){
                    self.folders.push(response.data[i]);
                }else if(response.data[i].object_type.trim() == "MODEL"){
                    self.models.push(response.data[i]);
                }else {
                    self.files.push(response.data[i]);
                }
            }

            console.log(self.folders);
            console.log(self.models);
            console.log(self.files);
        });

    }

    $rootScope.$watch('selectedFolder',function(){
        if($rootScope.selectedFolder !== undefined){
            self.Init();
        }
    });

}})();
```

What this module does is that it list contents of a specific folder. Now every time I select a folder, the watcher listens and activates the init function

```
    $rootScope.$watch('selectedFolder',function(){
        if($rootScope.selectedFolder !== undefined){
            self.Init();
        }
    });
```

The Init function just retrieves the files from the server and group the files.

```
            for(var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                if(response.data[i].object_type.trim() == "FOLDER"){
                    self.folders.push(response.data[i]);
                }else if(response.data[i].object_type.trim() == "MODEL"){
                    self.models.push(response.data[i]);
                }else {
                    self.files.push(response.data[i]);
                }
            }

            console.log(self.folders);
            console.log(self.models);
            console.log(self.files);
```

Everything is working fine and I will pass the values to another directive.

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-show="ctrlBrowser.active">
<div class="panel-heading">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="panel-content">
    <content-group items="ctrlBrowser.folders">Folders</content-group>
    <content-group items="ctrlBrowser.files">Files</content-group>
    <content-group items="ctrlBrowser.models">Special Files</content-group>
</div>
```

And will display as follows.

```
Folders
  - Folder 1
  - Folder 2
Files
  - File 1
  - File 2
Models 
  - Model 1
```

But when I select another folder, since what it does is only push to the existing array, it will also display previous files.

```
Folders
  - Folder 1 (old)
  - Folder 2 (old)
  - Folder 3 (new)
  - Folder 4 (new)
Files
  - File 1 (old)
  - File 2 (old)
Models 
  - Model 1 (old)
```

Now I tried to work around this by setting the folders, files, and models array to [] every time the Init function is called.

```
  self.Init = function(){
        self.active = true;

        //----- Additional Code ------//

        self.folders = [];
        self.files = [];
        self.models = [];

        //----- End of Additional Code ------//


        var url = "curl.php";
        var data = {
            path: "ViewFiles",
            parent_id: "{\"user_id\":\"" + UserCredentials.ID + "\",\"parent_id\":\"" + $rootScope.selectedFolder + "\"}"
        };

        //---- Unchanged Codes ----//
  }
```

This still logs the items retrieved but does not render anything and gives me this.

```
Folders

Files

Models
```

What did I do wrong? How does code flow in this situation?

Its quite long and I tried to be specific as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question.

Instead of :

```
    self.folders = [];
    self.files = [];
    self.models = [];
```

I tried :

```
    self.folders.splice(0,self.folders.length);
    self.files.splice(0,self.files.length);
    self.models.splice(0,self.models.length);
```

I'm not quite sure but I think angular watches every variable declaration and binds it. So if we reset the variable into [], I think it also removes the binding.

But im still open to suggestions and comments. thanks.